# How to spin Imported FBX model 360* in unity3d

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I have been trying to spin my imported wheel from blender 360* but when I do it, it doesn't rotate on the center (on one spot). I'm using C#.

I have tried this:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 5f - 90);
```

But this doesn't spin on one spot.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because your model's origin isn't in its center. You need to either

1. position your model in Blender so that its center is in the global origin

or

2. change the call to [`RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) which you can then for an example pass in `collider.bounds.center` to rotate around your collider's center position.

Comment: Please can you further explain on how to do the second option, thanks

Comment: `RotateAround` allows you to define the point to rotate around. Pass in the center point of your mesh or collider. Google will help you how to access those values.